# Inconsistency in data type when reading csv time data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading csv files with time data using Pandas. I have noticed that the data format of the timestamps varies depending on the time zone. I am not an expert here, so maybe I made a mistake. Here is a minimal example to illustrate what I mean.

I have two csv files: data1.csv:

```
Timestamp,State
2020-05-26T10:00:00+01:00,3
2020-05-26T10:10:00+00:00,1
```

and data2.csv:

```
Timestamp,State
2020-05-26T10:00:00+00:00,3
2020-05-26T10:10:00+00:00,1
```

Notice that the only difference is the time zone in the first row. When I read the first csv file, I get timestamps as Python datetimes (notice that I only look at the last row for which the timestamp is the same in both cases):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df_1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', parse_dates=['Timestamp'])

In [3]: df_1['Timestamp'].values[1]
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 26, 10, 10, tzinfo=tzutc())

In [4]: df_1.iloc[1].Timestamp
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 26, 10, 10, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

So that is fine. However, when I do the same for data2.csv, I get

```
In [5]: df_2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', parse_dates=['Timestamp'])

In [6]: df_2['Timestamp'].values[1]
Out[6]: numpy.datetime64('2020-05-26T10:10:00.000000000')

In [7]: df_2.iloc[1].Timestamp
Out[7]: Timestamp('2020-05-26 10:10:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

So now we have timestamps as Numpy datetime64 or Timestamps depending on how we extract them from the DataFrame.

It is annoying that the format is not consistent. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weakness of pandas: it can't natively represent columns with mixed timezones. See
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones for details.
Contrary to what is written there I get python `datetime` type (not `string`) for mixed timezone columns, but nevertheless it should answer your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

print(pd.__version__)

s1 = """Timestamp,State
2020-05-26T10:00:00+01:00,3
2020-05-26T10:10:00+00:00,1"""

s2 = """Timestamp,State
2020-05-26T10:00:00+00:00,3
2020-05-26T10:10:00+00:00,1"""

print('\n----- default:')

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s1), parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
print(df1, '\n', df1.applymap(type))

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s2), parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
print(df2, '\n', df2.applymap(type))

print('\n----- with date_parser:')

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s1), parse_dates=['Timestamp'], date_parser=lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, utc=True))
print(df1, '\n', df1.applymap(type))

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s2), parse_dates=['Timestamp'], date_parser=lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, utc=True))
print(df2, '\n', df2.applymap(type))
```

Output:

```
1.0.3

----- default:
                   Timestamp  State
0  2020-05-26 10:00:00+01:00      3
1  2020-05-26 10:10:00+00:00      1
                      Timestamp          State
0  <class 'datetime.datetime'>  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'datetime.datetime'>  <class 'int'>
                  Timestamp  State
0 2020-05-26 10:00:00+00:00      3
1 2020-05-26 10:10:00+00:00      1
                                            Timestamp          State
0  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...  <class 'int'>

----- with date_parser:
                  Timestamp  State
0 2020-05-26 09:00:00+00:00      3
1 2020-05-26 10:10:00+00:00      1
                                            Timestamp          State
0  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...  <class 'int'>
                  Timestamp  State
0 2020-05-26 10:00:00+00:00      3
1 2020-05-26 10:10:00+00:00      1
                                            Timestamp          State
0  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...  <class 'int'>
```